# Disadvantages of jQuery

Tags: jquery

I´m just wondering if using jQuery has a negative effect on the performance and as a result if I should only use it if I really need it. Or asked another way: Are there any disadvantages when using jQuery.

Shouldn´t it be quiet a big deal for the browser to include a file with so much code?

Comment: My guess is that you've probably not yet outgrown jQuery

Comment: Actually I haven´t done any jQuery yet because I always thought that it can´t be too good for the performance.. Now I asked just to see if that´s true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do.

jQuery and similar libraries are great for taking care of things like asynchronous operations (AJAX, Deferreds, etc.) aacross multiple different browsers and versions.

The downside is the weight of the library (sometimes >100kb) and crutch it creates for developers.

Vanilla javascript is the best way to go for performance, as shown [here](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Do you have a specific use case? This answer could fill an entire book.

Comment: Well not exactly. So far I did only Javascript but there were some situations, where it seemed comfortable to use jQuery. So I was wondering if I better shouldn´t if it is just a thing about saving a little coding time.

Comment: The right answer for you will depend on your specific use case. If only need to do simple things like DOM manipulation, using plain JS is the fastest performing solution. If you are doing more complex things, like multiple async operations (like promises) or having to support older browsers, jQuery could be a good solution that will save you tons of testing time. Comfort is one factor for using jQuery but that should be balanced with other concerns. Do you have a specific use case in mind?

Comment: Well I think after what you guys told me it´s best to go with Java Script. Since I am doing almost only DOM manipulation.

Comment: You know... it's like driving a Ferrari with a piece of wood stuck on the accelerator !... Let's remove the stick and learn how the tools are really working ? There is a whole discussion about speed and... compatibility ! It's good if your code is doing 12k op/s... well does it work on IE9 ?

Comment: It does work in IE9 but doesn´t in IE8. But I dont care about that :D

Answer (score 1):

Minified jQuery v2.1.3 is 33.63KB. This isn't unreasonably heavy.

The answer to these sorts of questions varies on a case by case basis. It depends on what you are using jQuery for (i.e. whether it would be easy to write the same code in vanilla JavaScript in a cross-browser way), how many other resources you are loading, etc. When in doubt, refer to data:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

Answer (score 0):

I remember there was one case where jQuery performance was an issue. I created this game mobile game [DruckX](http://www.druckxthegame.eu) and it's written in JS running in PhoneGap. When the user clicks on a tile, there are several animations triggering (timer + new tiles slide down) and on my mobile, the slide down animation was sputtering. So for this one line of code, I replaced the jQuery animate() function with velocity.js and it worked great. So my recommendation would be do everything in jQuery (the benefits are huge: cross-browser + clean code) and if you ever find a performance issue, then work to fix that particular issue.